# Creating Buttons Once Press Sounds play C# Xamarin( Visual Studio)

Tags: c#, android, button, xamarin

.I have a small Question, making a small app.

Each button plays one sound and I managed to make one button play that one sound, but I just can't figure out how to make the second button to do it. Any ideas?

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Media;

namespace SoundApp
{
 [Activity(Label = "SoundApp", MainLauncher = true, Icon =      "@mipmap/icon")]
 public class MainActivity : Activity
 {
    MediaPlayer _player;
    Button playButton;
    Button playButton1;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        void PlayButton_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            _player = MediaPlayer.Create(this, Resource.Raw.mysound);

            playButton = FindViewById<Button>(SoundApp.Resource.Id.playButton);
            playButton.Click += PlayButton_Click;
        }



        void PlayButton1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            // Second Button
            _player = MediaPlayer.Create(this, Resource.Raw.A);

            playButton1 = FindViewById<Button>(SoundApp.Resource.Id.playButton1);
            playButton1.Click += PlayButton1_Click;
        }

      }
 }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please review our [SO Question Checklist](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer. Please paste a minimal, complete, and verifiable example of the code you have already tried.
"but the second Button i just dont know how to figure it out" is not a good question. What is the problem? in your code I see only one button.

Comment: Here is the rest of the code.. for the second buttons,once i deploy to my Phone, it keeps playing same sound, doesn't matter which button i press. Will try to post my code when i add second button

Comment: why are you assigning event handlers to buttons inside of the event handler?  That doesn't make any sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Jason said, **don't assigning event handlers to buttons inside of the event handler**. Modify your code like this :

```
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    MediaPlayer _player;
    Button playButton;
    Button playButton1;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        playButton = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.playButton);
        playButton.Click += PlayButton_Click;

        playButton = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.playButton1);
        playButton.Click += PlayButton1_Click;

        void PlayButton_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            _player = MediaPlayer.Create(this, Resource.Raw.mysound);
            _player.Start();
        }

        void PlayButton1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            // Second Button
            _player = MediaPlayer.Create(this, Resource.Raw.A);
            _player.Start();
        }

    }
}
```